# Office Web Apps - Edit PDF - WopiFrame: failed to generate iframe URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-web-apps, pdf

Our Office Web Apps server seems to cause an error in SharePoint when opening a PDF:

- Clicking on the link to the PDF in the Document Library opens "Word Web App" and renders the PDF fine (in read-only mode). The URL Action is "Default":

  [image]
- Clicking on the "..." ellipsis (ECB/callout) actions menu and then selecting "Open" causes an error. The URL Action is "Edit" which suggests "Word Web App" has an issue with editing a PDF (you'd expect it to give you the prompt to save it as a Word Doc):

  [image]

  [image]

The ULS seems to log some strange "Wopi" errors:

`09/12/2013 15:19:41.88   w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ah6ud   Unexpected  Exiting GetWOPITargetInternal Early - GenerateWacUrl failed to produce a URL/actionEntry for file [FILE].pdf with extension 'PDF' StackTrace:   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPWOPIHost.GetWOPITargetInternal(HttpContext httpContext, SPWeb web, Object& spPrimeObject, SPWOPIAction& requestedAction, SPRegionalSettings spSettings, String& wopiAppUrl, String& wopiFavIconUrl, String& wopiAccessToken, Int64& wopiAccessTokenTtl, String& errorMessageToDisplay, String& redirectUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WOPIFrameHelper.OnLoadHelper(WOPIFrame frame)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WOPIFrameHelper.OnLoad(WOPIFrame frame)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean inc...    922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f
09/12/2013 15:19:41.88* w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ah6ud   Unexpected  ...ludeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.HttpContext.InvokeCancellableCallback(WaitCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Web.UI.Page.LegacyAsyncPageBeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) ...  922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f
09/12/2013 15:19:41.88* w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ah6ud   Unexpected  ...    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr ...  922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f
09/12/2013 15:19:41.88* w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ah6ud   Unexpected  ...nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f
09/12/2013 15:19:41.88  w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            aht19   High        WopiFrame: failed to generate iframe URL.   922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f
09/12/2013 15:19:41.94  w3wp.exe (0x1CD0)                           0x0A00  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/12/2013 15:19:41.92, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}   922c429c-d091-108c-7801-fd05116e821f`

Anyone know how to fix?

---

Update: there was one possibly related issue I found on the net related to TMG - but I don't think this is the problem (we're inside the firewall and I tried putting an explicit proxy bypass on the server name - which didn't help).

[image]
http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/spc/2012/SPC096_Baginski.pptx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We raised the issue with Microsoft Support and apparently it's a bug. Will know more soon. In the meantime, the fix is to disable PDF's from being rendered in OWA:

`Get-SPWOPIBinding –Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false`

Control whether PDFs open in Word Web App or the default PDF reader
http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2013/07/24/control-whether-pdfs-open-in-word-web-app-or-the-default-pdf-reader.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed in the October 2013 CU: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825665

Answer (score 1):

On this page, http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/planning.html, section 3.4.2.5 may help you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE! Can you please expand your answer with an abstract of the paragraphs you find important from the link? Chances are this link will break one day, and then your answer will stop being helpful. Again, a warm welcome to SP.SE!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the pdf preview in a doc lib and don't care about the opening the pdf in the webapp view you can use the SPwopiBinding -Action "interactivepreview" and remove the default -Action "view".  This will allow the doc preview within the doc lib be clicking the ellipsis and open the pdf in the browser.  Your webapp broswer file handling should be set to "Permissive".  The powershell to remove the SPWopibinding for -Action "view is as follows:

```
Get-SPwopiBinding -Action "view" -Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWopiBinding -Confirm $false
```